# Is there any way to auto increment float values just as we do integers with serial datatype in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

| column | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1.1 | 1.0 |
| 1.1.2 | 1.1 |
| 1.1.3 | 1.2 |

Here, I want these to be auto-incremented. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Which column should be auto-incremented? And where do you stop incrementing the digits in `column2`? at 1.9999 or at 1.9999999 or at 1.999999999999999999?

Comment: I don't think these are floats and the first column isn't a number at all. In both of these columns I'd guess 1.9 is followed by 1.10 not 2.0. If you just want the last part of this version-looking value to be incremented, hide this table behind a view, make your column a regular `serial` data type, and define the view to prepend your desired prefix upon select. [Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/P2U1dtlJ)